# How do I access a movieclip inside a movieclip by it's instance name?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have several movieclips (with the instance names my_mc0, my_mc1, ... my_mc8) inside another movieclip (instance name: main_mc).
I know I can access any of the child movieclips like this: main_mc.my_mc0.whatever
but since I have 9 childs there, I'd like to use a loop that goes over them.
something like that :

```
enter code here

for (i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    this["main_mc.my_mc" + i].whatever
}
```

the code above doesn't work ofcourse.
couldn't find the answer anywhere...
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "this" (which I am guessing refers to the stage/root), try replacing it with whatever the containing movieclip is.

```
this.main_mc["my_mc" + i]
```

Or if main_mc is inside another movieclip (anotherClip):

```
this.anotherClip.main_mc["my_mc" + i]
```

and so forth. Hopefully you get the idea on what is going on.

Comment: also, if main_mc was a dynamic name, you could use this["main_mc"]["my_mc" + i]